# How to add SUPER priviledge to MySQL in pythonanywhere?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, pythonanywhere

I am using PythonAnywhere to host my web application for testing purpose. My frontend and python script is working fine. Now I want to connect it to MySQL database. I have uploaded my **.sql** file to the **mysite** folder and trying to restore it using this syntax:

```
mysql -u username -h username.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com 'username$scm' < ab.sql
```

as told in [Backing up (and restoring) MySQL databases](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/MySQLBackupRestore) (where username=created username) but it's throwing this error:

```
ERROR 1419 (HY000) at line 88: You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_
trust_function_creators variable)
```

I've tried to fix this error by following this [How to grant super privilege to the user?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63404/how-to-grant-super-privilege-to-the-user) but still it's throwing error:

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'username'@'%' to database 'username$scm'
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the answer on [PythonAnywhere forums](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/20376/#id_post_68321):

> You would not be able to get super privileges on MySQL (only
>   postgres). Could you disable binary logging before doing the restore?
>   You could either try to edit the ab.sql file to take out that line, or
>   turn it off from wherever you were creating the sqldump originally,
>   and doing the sqldump again.

Comment: ok somehow I managed to get rid of this problem but now a new type of issue is occurring. My database tables have triggers attached with it but what I saw its that the triggers are not working. How can I fix this ?

Comment: Triggers aren't supported on PythonAnywhere, unfortunately :-(